# Get Magento Sub-Categories in Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using the code below to get all the subcategories of category '9'. 
The code works great, but it sort the subcategory by id or creation date, I need to sort the subcategories alphabetically.

```
<?php
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 9);

foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
    <?php 
        $entity_id = $cat->getId();
        $name = $cat->getName();
        $url_key = $cat->getUrlKey();
        $url_path = $cat->getUrlPath();
        $skin_url = $cat->getImageUrl();
    ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $url_path ?>">
            <?php 
                echo '<img style="width: 100%;" src="'.$skin_url.'" />';
            ?>

            <div class="brand-border-top"></div>
            <div class="brand-border-bottom"></div>
            <div class="brand-overlay">
                <?php echo $name = $cat->getName(); ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');
```

In your case

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 9)->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');
```